# SQL Query with if statement

Tags: sql, database

I have a table which has a `` `department` `` column (allows null) but when I select that table and the field is null I don't want it to show Null but "-".

I'm told to put the if statement inside the select statement but I can't figure it out. How can I do this?

Comment: Poor question. Show your table structure, sample data, what you have tried so far and specify more clearly what exactly do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the function `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(department, '-')
from table t
```

This is an ANSI standard function available in most databases.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two methods:

**1.** Using `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN department IS NULL 
            THEN '-' 
            ELSE department 
            END AS department FROM TableName
```

`CASE` evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible result expressions. Read more [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

**2.** Using `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE (department,'-') FROM TableName
```

`COALESCE` returns first parameter which is not null. Read more [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use following code:

select ISNULL(department, '-') AS DEPARTM
from dbo.tbl_Department
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation as to what exactly the code does and how it helps solve the problem.

Comment: ISNull is a inbuilt function of ms-sql which returns a value if field is null, so when department will be null it returns '-' if only department is also varchar type if its not then it should convert into varchar using cast. Regards

Comment: why i should do that according to me above code i mentioned will definitely work.

Comment: It is not about whether your code is working or not. It is about how understandable your answer is to a common reader. Any fool can write code that a computer understands. Good programmers write code that humans can understand. Please add a line or two of explanation and some reference links to your answer to support the code.

Comment: okey but i think this is a very basic level question and any programmer have .1 % of knowledge about sql has knowledge about this, and my answer was only for programmers not for fools, i can't do spoon fitting sorry. 
Regards,

Comment: I feel very sad when I see people consider two programmers the same. I strongly disagree. The levels of expertise of programmers on SO differs vastly from programmer to programmer. You cannot presume people to know things that you know. Moreover, if you don't want to do any "spoon fitting", why did you even answer? You could have left a simple comment. There are three more answers that are almost similar to yours. What different are you doing in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the 'CASE WHEN' statement in your select query. Like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Department IS NULL THEN Department = '-'
END AS DEPARTMENT
FROM Table_Name
```